# xcode 4.3 and iOS SDK 5.1 trouble

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

hm, i have an strange problem...
i just wanted to test an app on my ipad but i cant deploy it, because my ipad runs ios 5.1 and in xcode i can only select a deployment target up to 5.0.

So, i think i have to install the new SDK for 5.1 - but how?
I cant download xcode 4.3.2 (which includes the new sdk) because in the "App store" it says "installed" - if i open the "about xcode" tab in xcode, the version there is 4.3 (not 4.3.2)...

what can/should i do to install the new sdk?

Comment: Thanks for the accept... but I think you accepted the wrong answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try your organizer > Downloads > Components (check & install) > iOS 5.1 support

you can find the organizer in the top right corner of your xcode.

also you can check in your App Store the tab 'updates' if an updated version of your xcode is available.

Comment: OMG - u saved my day!!! i never saw the update tab before ;) why isnt that displayed on the xcode site in the App Store??? thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check you are opening the correct version of XCode from the Applications folder.

XCode is now installed in there when you get the latest from the App Store. You may possibly be using an old shortcut to the previous version in the Developer folder?

Comment: possible, but 4.3 (without .2) was a single .app too